# interop.excel funciona en una PC y en otra no

Tags: excel, vb.net, interop

tengo una app de winForms en .net 7.0.
Para el proyecto como tengo que extraer a excel referencio microsof.office.interop.excel (Excel 16.0 objet Library)
El inconveniente es que en una de las maquinas no funciona. En ambas tengo instalado office 365. Lo curioso es que tengo otra aplicacion per esta en framework 4.8 y funciona perfectamente en todas las maquinas, desde la compilacion Relase o debug.

En VisualStudio cuando estoy en la maquina que no funciona cuando hago la referencia COM la marca con un signo de advertencia si lo hago en la aplicación 7.0
Si es dentro de la app en framework 4.8 sin ningun problema.
Tambien intente instalar interop.excel desde nuGet, pero lo mismo me dice que la version es anterior.

El mensaje de error es: *"Could not load file or assemby 'office, Version = 15.0.0.0, el sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"*. Dejo el codigo, por las dudas, pero no creo que sea problema de codigo ya que con el mismo codigo funciona en otras maquinas

```
Imports excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Module ControlExcel
    Public AppExcel As Excel.Application
    Public LibroExcel As Excel.Workbook
    Public HojaExcel As Excel.Worksheet

    Public Sub IniciarExcel()
        AppExcel = New Excel.Application
        AppExcel.Visible = True
        LibroExcel = AppExcel.Workbooks.Add
        HojaExcel = LibroExcel.Worksheets(1)

    End Sub

    Public Sub ConvierteTabla()
        Dim range As Excel.Range = HojaExcel.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
        Dim tabla As Excel.ListObject = HojaExcel.ListObjects.Add(
            Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, , Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes)

        range.Columns.AutoFit()

        range = HojaExcel.Range("G1").CurrentRegion
        tabla = HojaExcel.ListObjects.Add(
            Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, , Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes)

        range.Columns.AutoFit()


    End Sub
End Module
```

Hay algo que evidentemente desconozco en la asignación de las referencias, o algo que esta mal en la maquina que no funciona. Agradezco de antemano